# direct Single Register Addressing AVR

Tags: assembly, avr

I was looking at Direct Single Register Addressing in Atmel AVR instruction set. In Page# 3 of instruction Set manual, it is written that Direct Single Register Addressing instruction contains Rd in bits 0 to 4 and opcode in rest of the 12 bits.  In such case where is the immediate value of 8 bits located? The figure 1 in the manual does not indicate the immediate value.
Ex: LDI R18,0xff : In this instruction, if 5 bits are register address and 11 bits are Opcode, there is no immediate data!

Or is Opcode is of 4 bits and rest are all for data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram you copied is only the *concept* of the single register addressing. You should scroll down to the concrete instructions to see how the operands are encoded.

For example, LDI (Page 89 in [this copy](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/32789696.PDF)) uses a 4-bit opcode, 4 bits of the immediate value, then 4 bits for selecting the register, then the other 4 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It's arranged something like this for you're example of the LDI instruction:

```
OOOO KKKK KKKK DDDD
```

Where O is opcode, K is the immediate data and D is the destination register.  You can find all of this stuff in the [Atmel AVR Assembler](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LDI.html) documentation. The endianess is swizzled around from your diagram.

Comment: Hi Jaket. Regarding the DDDD at the end, doesn't this max out at 15? The docs specify that this loads an 8-bit constant directly to register 16 to 31, but how are we to know that it's 16-31 from those 4-bits?

Comment: Maybe you forgot about 0.  0..15 is 16 unique values. 16..31 are 16 unique registers.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks jaket!